# How can i trigger $routeUpdate event of Angular without changing the URL?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular UI App, where my application logic works unfortunately based on URL change.. So first i change the URL with $location.search, then the event $routeUpdate is triggered, there i have my logic:

```
$scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function () {
    ... // logic
});
```

Now i also want to trigger that event in one case, in which i dont have a URL change. How can i do that?

Of course i can also write

```
$scope.$emit("$routeUpdate");
```

But it seems like a hack to me.. is there any other better way of doing it?

Comment: you may extract the common logic to some service\factory.

Comment: It's not an hack unless your are effectively modifing the route.

Comment: ok thanks.. i think we stay with "$scope.$emit("$routeUpdate");" for now..